# I'm getting an undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass...but it is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, instance-variables, railsapps

I've been searching for hours but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm new to ruby on rails and I can't figure out how to fix this. What caused the problem is that I moved an instance variable from one file to another and now no links are working and the error always displays: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

here is my code:

Application.html.erb:

```
    <% number = 1 %>
      <% @projects.each do |project| %>
      <%= link_to project, id: "a-#{number}" do %>
      <div class="flex">
          <div class="each--project" id="project-<%= number %>">
              <h3><%= project.title %></h3>
              <p class="date"><%= project.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d")%></p>
              <p class="content"><%= project.description %></p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <% number = number + 1 %>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

application_controller.rb

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      def index
         @projects = Project.all
      end
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    end
```

projects_controller

```
        class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
          before_action :find_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
          before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
          def index
           @projects = Project.all.order("created_at desc")
          end

          def new
           @project = Project.new
          end

          def create
           @project = Project.new project_params

          if @project.save
           redirect_to @project, notice: "Yay Mia! That project was             saved!"
          else
             render 'new'
          end
         end

         def show
         end

         def edit
         end

         def update
           if @project.update project_params
             redirect_to @project, notice: "Yay Mia! That project was updated!"
           else
             render 'edit'
           end
         end

         def destroy
           @project.destroy
           redirect_to projects_path
         end


         private

         def find_project
           @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
         end

         def project_params
           params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :link, :slug)
         end

       end
```

routes rb

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     devise_for :users
     resources :posts
     resources :projects
     resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
     get 'welcome/index'
     root 'welcome#index'

     get '*path' => redirect('/')
   end
```

Comment: What routes are you getting the error on? All of them or only certain ones?

Comment: it was on all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `index` action on the `ApplicationController`
You can however achieve the same thing with a `before_action` if you want it loaded for all actions in all controllers. This is not something I would recommend though.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_projects

  def load_projects
    @projects = Project.all
  end
end
```

Hint:

```
<% number = 1 %>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
```

can be much better written as

```
<% @projects.each_with_index do |project, number| %>
```

Comment: That's great, I would however reconsider how you are doing things, you should only really put this `before_action` in the controllers where you need them, unless of course you really need them everywhere.

Comment: this is going to show up on every page because it's part of the footer, so I think it does make sense to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referencing something in your main application layout then it must be loaded for *every* controller. Putting it in one specific controller only engages it when that controller is in use, which it will only be on very specific routes.

If `@projects` needs to be populated on every request, move that to a `load_projects` method and add a `before_action` filter in your main ApplicationController. Putting it in a default `index` method doesn't work, that will never get run.

You can always stub in `Rails.logger.debug('...')` type calls to see if your code is actually being exercised. Watch `log/development.log` constantly to see what's happening. Most problems can be quickly resolved by examining what's been logged.